# Where to study Cortex R architecture?

Tags: arm, cpu, computer-architecture, cortex, instruction-set

I am interested to study Cortex-R architecture but I cannot find its details online. Is it proprietary detail or should I ask for this information from arm.com? Obviously I am not looking for the blueprint of the core but only its architectural information. Is it possible that I will get it online or not?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because stack exchange is not a human-mediated search engine.  Stack exchange sites are reserved only for the questions which remain after basic attempts at self research. The materials you seek are trivially found with a web search for "Cortex-R manual".  Requests for links to off-site content are in general off-topic throughout the stack exchange system.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the ARM website you can get the [Technical Reference Manuals](https://developer.arm.com/docs/ddi0363/latest/preface), [Programmers Guide](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.den0042a/index.html&_ga=2.14908726.1425301612.1565174942-1109088555.1562151154), and [Architecture Reference Manual](https://static.docs.arm.com/ddi0406/c/DDI0406C_C_arm_architecture_reference_manual.pdf), those links are for the R4, but others are easy to find.